# Error running nmap on root privilege - Linux

Tags: linux, debian, nmap

I just started linux, and now i'm trying to mess with `nmap`. I can run other apps on root without a problem except for nmap.

```
user@localhost:/etc$ sudo nmap -O scanme.nmap.org

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-08-15 11:29 UTC
nmap: netutil.cc:3285: int route_dst_netlink(const sockaddr_storage*, rout
e_nfo*, const char*, const sockaddr_storage*): Assertion `p != NULL' faile
d.
Aborted
```

but I can run nmap just fine without root when the option doesn't require it

Comment: I'd recommend updating nmap and see if the issue persists.  The scan you submitted worked for me on Nmap 7.70

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Some options which I would go trough

Try to open the file via zenmap. Maybe the GUI shows more informations or it solves the problem.

Check if this file is not corrupted.

Check if you have permissions for this file (also as user)